# Reverse Post Order for Specific Category

Tags: php, wordpress, post, reverse

I have 3 categories in WordPress - Events, News and Webinars.

I would like to reverse the default post order for the category 'Events' to sort in ascending order while the others to sort in descending order. I have tried using the following code in functions.php:

```
function change_category_order( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_category('10') && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'orderby', 'date' ); 
        $query->set( 'order', 'ASC' );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'change_category_order' );
```

'10' being the category ID, however, nothing seems to happen.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is returned and noting is being assigned from the function.
Untested but I assume this will work:

```
function change_category_order( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_category('10') && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'orderby', 'date' ); 
        $query->set( 'order', 'ASC' );
    }
    return $query;
}
$newquery = add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'change_category_order' );
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, Andreas! Unfortunately, this didn't work either. I am fairly new to coding so I have been trying to find solutions online but to no avail. I can either have all posts sort in an ascending order or descending but when I attempt to add a filter, nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

Very late to the party, but I have developed a free plugin that does exactly that: it reverses the post order for a specific category in a way that the oldest posts appear on top of the category archive page. You can choose the post order for every category from the dashboard, so no coding skills are required: [Post Order By Category](https://yonkov.github.io/post/change-post-order-for-a-specific-category-in-wordpress/)